how to apply MUI component theme?
For example, if I want to make my button have the same effect as the MUI Button, then I would like to apply all the classes from the MUI Button to my button tag. How should I do this? Not using styled. Nor using sx. Because using sx might involve writing a lot of CSS. Is there a simpler method?

Why not just use a MUI button?

because i want use this component,i want apply MUI style on https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-tree-select
